# Is there anything I can do about different browsers rendering fonts differently?

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts

I have a UL whose LI are styled with the following:

```
Ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   background: transparent;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(9, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

However the fonts looks different, a little thicker in Chrome:

[image]

Then it does in Safari:

[image]

I prefer the Safari rendition, how can I get the font to be rendered identical in every browser?

Comment: The short answer is: no. It's really a pain in the ... But you can try to make things better by using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` and `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`on the HTML element in your CSS.

Comment: @Connum that actually made a huge difference, thanks lol

Comment: That's great! I added my comment as an answer, feel free to accept it.

Comment: protip: don't rely on the OS to have the font you want. For instance, Helvetica Neue is an Apple-only font, your website will look nothing like what you hope on other computers, and likely not the same even on two devices that are both Apple but have different versions of Helvetica Neue. If you want typographical control, specify your font resource with an `@font-face` rule.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no. It's really a pain in the ... But you can try to make things better by using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` and `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` on the HTML element in your CSS.